# Not able to show the errors after user type some value in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in Ionic Project and I have used form but when I am showing the errors  so my errors are not coming.

This is my **orderform.html**:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p class="newp11">Order Number: {{orderpa}}</p>
  <h2 class="myformh2">Fill Your Account Detail's</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="cancelorderde" (ngSubmit)="cancelorderDetails()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="IFSC Code*" type="text" formControlName="ifsc_code" required></ion-input>
        <p *ngIf="cancelorderde.controls['ifsc_code'].errors" class="danger" padding>IFSC Code Is Not Valid</p>
      </ion-item>
      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!cancelorderde.valid" ion-button type="submit" class="newbtn11" color="primary" block>Cancel Order</button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

In this html, I have shown one error but it is not coming as the user type some wrong input.

This is my **orderform.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cancelorder',
  templateUrl: 'cancelorder.html',
})
export class CancelorderPage {
  cancelorderde : FormGroup;
  orderpa: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.cancelorderde = this.formBuilder.group({
        holder_name: ['', Validators.required],
        bank_name: ['', Validators.required],
        branch_name: ['', Validators.required],
        account_number: ['', Validators.required],
        ifsc_code: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$')
        ])],
        mobile_number: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.maxLength(10),
          Validators.minLength(10),
          Validators.required
        ])],
        reason: ['', Validators.required],
        remark: ['', Validators.required],
      });

     this.orderpa = navParams.get('orderno');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CancelorderPage');
  }

  cancelorderDetails()
  {
     console.log(this.cancelorderde.value);
  }

}
```

In this ts file, I have validated the IFSC Code but after that also the error is not coming but the user is not able to click on Submit Button.

I want that when the user enter the wrong input, it should the error to the user and when there is no error, user can click on submit button.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try This: It will work.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p class="newp11">Order Number: {{orderpa}}</p>
  <h2 class="myformh2">Fill Your Account Detail's</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="cancelorderde" (ngSubmit)="cancelorderDetails()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="IFSC Code*" type="text" formControlName="ifsc_code" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <p *ngIf="cancelorderde.controls['ifsc_code'].errors && cancelorderde.controls['ifsc_code'].dirty && cancelorderde.get('ifsc_code').touched" class="danger" padding>IFSC Code Is Not Valid</p>
      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!cancelorderde.valid" ion-button type="submit" class="newbtn11" color="primary" block>Cancel Order</button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Move **p tag** out of the **item tag**. It will show the error according to the question asked and solved your problem.